# iPad application crashes on starting camera

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, qr-code, ip-camera

I am creating an application in which i need to start camera and scan QR code. I am using a class in through which scanner starts. it is fine in iPhone but crashes in iPad.
    i am using the code

```
if(![[appDelegate.tabbarcontroller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] isMovingFromParentViewController]) { 
    [[appDelegate.tabbarcontroller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: and what about posting some code here?

Comment: ...and don't forget to post the error you're getting in the crash logs :)

Comment: Maybe you try on 1st iPad that has no camera?

Comment: Have you received any memory warnings?

Comment: @AdilSoomro please check the line on which it crashes.

Comment: Please revise your formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **defensive programming** in iOS is a very good strategy to prevent crashes.

About your question, from Apple doc:

> To use an image picker controller containing its default controls,
> perform these steps:
>
> Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired
> source. Do this calling the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method,
> providing a constant from the “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType”
> enum.
>
> Check which media types are available, for the source type
> you’re using, by calling the availableMediaTypesForSourceType: class
> method. This lets you distinguish between a camera that can be used
> for video recording and one that can be used only for still images.

The link [iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/) by **Mugunth Kumar** provides the info you need to checke against device capabilities.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the AVAuthorization status using the code below
when use the media.

```
/*
// Media types
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeVideo    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeAudio    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeText    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeClosedCaption    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeSubtitle    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeTimecode    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeMetadata    NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVMediaTypeMuxed    NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
*/

AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    // authorized
    NSLog(@"authorized");
}
else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    // denied
    NSLog(@"denied");
}
else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
{
    // restricted
    NSLog(@"restricted");
}
else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    // not determined
    NSLog(@"not determined");

    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if(granted){ // Access has been granted ..do something

        } else { // Access denied ..do something

        }
    }];
}
```